# Ease out on when leaving hover state CSS3

Tags: html, css

Another CSS3 question. I have managed to rotate(360) an image on hover but it retains it's speed when leaving the hovered state. Ideally I'm looking for a solution to slow the speed when leaving the hovered state. I know there's a property(ease-out) to achieve this but I can't seem to get a working solution. After many attempts, I was hoping to get some pointers.

Markup:

```
<div class="account-holder">
    <img src="/images/profile/avatar.png" class="my-image"/>
    <p><strong>Welcome</strong>Terry Wingfield</p>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
.my-image 
{
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s; 
   -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
   -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
   transition-duration: 0.8s;

   -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
   -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
   -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
   transition-property: transform;    
}

  .my-image:hover 
  {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
     -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
   }
```

I have stripped it back to what I originally had. Any help would be appreciated and thoughts on re-writing the styles above to shorthand would be very welcome.

Regards,

Comment: Do you want to have a different rotation speed for on/off hover?

Comment: @JasonK Yes sorry, i was hoping to get a slower speed when leaving the hovered state (off). Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [this](http://css-tricks.com/different-transitions-for-hover-on-hover-off/) awesome article. You put your code in `.my-image` for `hover off` (mouseleave) transitions. And for `hover on` you put your code in `.my-image:hover`.

So your final code would be:

```
.my-image {
    /* Slower transition off hover */
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s; 
       -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
         -o-transition-duration: 1s;
            transition-duration: 1s;

    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
       -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
         -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
            transition-property: transform;    
}


.my-image:hover {
    /* Faster transition on hover */
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s; 
       -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
         -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
            transition-duration: 0.5s;

    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
       -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
         -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
            transform:rotate(360def);
}
```

I hope this works.

Comment: Hi, worked like a dream! Thanks for the quick response. Good find with the link! I may need to invest some dev time with CSS3. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand, you want to decrease change animation speed. So that, I did some changes in your `CSS` codes. Consequently, your codes look like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4pcy2jjs/):

Markup:

```
 <div class="account-holder">
    <img src="/images/profile/avatar.png" class="my-image"/>
    <p><strong>Welcome</strong>Terry Wingfield</p>
 </div>
```

Styles:

```
.my-image 
{
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease-in;
   -moz-transition: -moz-transform 2s ease-in;
   -o-transition: -o-transform 2s ease-in;
   transition: transform 2s ease-in;    
}

.my-image:hover 
{
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in;
   -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s ease-in;
   -o-transition: -o-transform 1s ease-in;
   transition: transform 1s ease-in; 
   -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
   -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
   -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

I hope this will solves your problem :)

Comment: Hi coni, Thanks for the response but I already awarded the answer to above. Thanks for your time.